# Qt/C++ Give pointer to another constructor

Tags: c++, qt

So i hope someone can help me again with the following.
I want to use a pointer from one class in another one.

***car.h***

```
class wheel;

class car : public QMainWindow
{
public:
    car (QWidget *parent = 0);

    wheel *test;
};

class wheel : QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
public:
    wheel();

    void hoverEnterEvent (QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent*);
};
```

***car.cpp***

```
#include "car.h"

wheel::wheel()
{

}

car::car (QWidget*)
{
    test = new wheel;
    test -> setAcceptHoverEvents (true);
}

wheel::hoverEnterEvent (QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent*)
{
    test -> setPixmap (/*thePixmap*/);
}
```

The problem is, i cant use the pointer "test" in class wheel,
and i really dont know how i can do this "without" making the pointer "test" global.

Comment: Use `this` instead of `test`.

Comment: I suggest you get your hands on a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) before you tackle Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wheel::hoverEnterEvent` is part of the wheel class. It doesn't need a pointer to itself to operate on itself, so just replace

```
test -> setPixmap (/*thePixmap*/);
```

with

```
setPixmap (/*thePixmap*/);
```